# Linux tool to monitor bandwidth consumption of a specific process (PID)

Tags: networking, monitoring

Is there tool or a command that helps capture the bandwidth consumption of specific process (PID), just like the System Monitor does, but for a single specific process, as shows the following screenshot [image]

I will be happy with a command line tool that at least exports such history to files. (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04)

**Update 1**

I want at least a tool like [Nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net) that can output into files (Nethogs captures only TCP connexions) a similar tool that targets both TCP and UDP would be great

**Update 2**

Any script, combination of other tools (like wireshark) would help too.

Comment: [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) (and pcap), or a higher level tool like [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So since I didn't find any easy/clear/"hit the ground running" solution, I had to made a modest one, fixes, refactoring and more options to come.

-> https://github.com/AymenDaoudi/NeTraf

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the tool atop? According to the man page for it:

"Network load is shown per process if the kernel module `netatop' has been installed."

Comment: I could not install netatop on ubuntu 20.04. Do you have any instructions?

Answer (score 2):

Nethogs might be what you want.

debian/ubuntu/etc

```
apt-get install nethogs
```

or rhel/cent/etc

```
yum install nethogs
```

You run it on the network interface, e.g.

```
nethogs eth0
```

However, its output is bandwidth per process, sent and received. You can also monitor multiple interfaces.

DESCRIPTION
       NetHogs is a small 'net top' tool. Instead of breaking the traffic down
       per protocol or per subnet, like most such tools do,  it  groups  band‐
       width  by  process - and does not rely on a special kernel module to be
       loaded. So if there's suddenly a lot of network traffic, you  can  fire
       up  NetHogs  and immediately see which PID is causing this, and if it's
       some kind of spinning process, kill it.

**UPDATE**: OP asked for output to file. You can do it with nethogs:

```
nethogs -d 1 eth0 > output.txt
```

-d specifies the time interval in between writes... so you could do the above command and get the desired result.

**UPDATE2** OP says TCP and UDP is a requirement. Then attempt to use [jnettop](http://jnettop.kubs.info/wiki/). A bit older, but does TCP and UDP. It is available in deb/ubuntu and I think RHEL derivatives. example:

```
jnettop --display text -t 5 --format CSV
```

This should be pipe-able to a file.

Comment: I clearly state in the question that Nethogs supports TCP connexions only and I aim to do profiling on an application that uses both TCP and UDP

Comment: You clearly stated "TCP and UDP _would_ be great". Sorry for my mis-interpretation. I will update my response.

Comment: @number9 jnettop seems to be interesting, how ever outputing to a file is not continues, is there a way to log the data continuously as long as I'm using my profiled Application, just like the data is displayed continuously on the screen ?

Comment: @number9 the jnettop command doesn't show PIDs too

Answer (score 0):

How about using `iftop`, to analyze the amount of traffic on certain ports, and then using `lsof` to determine which process is using which port?

Comment: can `iftop` report KB/s for UPs and Downs can it output that to an external file ?

Answer (score 0):

nethogs tool will help to monitor network traffic per process.
you can use `nethogs -t`.
here -t is for traverse.

to display total Send and Recv use below command.
`nethogs -t -v3`

you can redirect output into file for further process filtering.

Comment: Does not show PID.