# How to Track total internet / data usage of a specific app or a process for Linux (headless)

Tags: networking, scripting, quota

I would like to check the total use of the Internet for a process or application or a bash script (to set up a quota for my application).

I tried some applications and found it just giving download and upload speeds.

The reason I ask the question is to make a script that kills the application whenever the app's internet usage exceeds 5GB. Its a kind of setting quota limits for specific app.

Anyone can answer here, no matter the information is small or big please letme know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Data Usage Statistics Of Every Application In Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/628792/97255) or [How can I limit the bandwidth used by a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34116/97255)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux tool to monitor bandwidth consumption of a specific process (PID)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327223/linux-tool-to-monitor-bandwidth-consumption-of-a-specific-process-pid)